# "Specified Module cannot be Found. (MS Visual Database Tools)"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I installed `SQL SERVER 2008` then I create a database. Then I created a database diagram and received the following error:

`Specified Module cannot be Found. (MS Visual Database Tools)`

[image]

How can I resolve the error so a database diagram can be created?

Comment: http://i49.tinypic.com/68ej52.jpg

Comment: ABOVE IS THE LINK OF IMAGE WHICH I FACE ERROR AND NOT RESLOVE

Comment: Did you ever have SQL 2012 installed on this server?

Comment: nope i have sql server 2008 r2 butt now i unistall this and install sql server 2008 but it remains not work in database diagram @love2learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overcome this issue through the following steps:

1) Delete all files at the location.

```
[x64] C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSDesigners8

[x86] C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSDesigners8Hi
```

2) Copy and paste the below link in browser, go and download the file.

3) Extract the files and paste it int the previous location.

LINK : -> harshgupta71.blogspot.in/2013/02/the-specified-module-could-not-be-found.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete all files located on this folder:

```
[x64] C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSDesigners8

[x86] C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSDesigners8
```

and replace with some one that has sql server and have no problem or copy from some where that sql server have no problem.

based on:  [The specified module could not be found. (MS Visual Database Tools)](http://harshgupta71.blogspot.com/2013/02/the-specified-module-could-not-be-found.html)