# Error "The specified module could not be found" in Sql Server Diagram

Tags: sql, sql-server

I had already made ​​my Diagram.

But today when I double click it displays this error:

```
The specified module could not be found.
 (MS Visual Database Tools)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VirtualProject.Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ISqlVirtualProject.CreateDesigner(Urn origUrn, DocumentType editorType, DocumentOptions aeOptions, IManagedConnection con)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ISqlVirtualProject.CreateDesigner(Urn origUrn, DocumentType editorType, DocumentOptions aeOptions, IManagedConnection con)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ScriptFactory.CreateDesigner(DocumentType editorType, DocumentOptions aeOptions, Urn parentUrn, IManagedConnection mc)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VsDocumentMenuItem.CreateDesignerWindow(IManagedConnection mc, DocumentOptions options)
```

I think this error is caused by a uninstall software.

I do not know what software?

I've seen this link, but it did not work for me:

[“Specified Module cannot be Found. (MS Visual Database Tools)”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15230117/specified-module-cannot-be-found-ms-visual-database-tools)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I search and check this error, the mainly issue with not uninstall , but might be your configuration or registration issue in GAC or registry. Or might be not properly installed or your dll issue of visual studio with sqlserver.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d65c71f5-3887-4f2a-bbd3-e799a4ac6fdc/visual-studio-database-tools-error?forum=vstsdb

Are you try to delete files as you link you found.

Please check this link

http://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/28923-problems-with-sql-server-compact

https://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/management-studio-error-requested-15450.aspx

[getting error while creating new diagram in SQL Server 2008 R2/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17502208/getting-error-while-creating-new-diagram-in-sql-server-2008-r2)

you can restore sqlserver to resolve this as suggested in this link.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4cdd4fa7-fc20-4eb6-b2f5-2b801bf3337c/sql-server-2005-express-loading-problem

Comment: Thanks alot, but version of my sql server is 2005